gRPC Ruby Quick Start Fail: undefined method `build' for an instance of Google::Protobuf::DescriptorPool (NoMethodError)
I am following the example from the gRPC Ruby Quick Start guide, but I encounter an error when trying to run the server using the command ruby greeter_server.rb. The specific error message I receive is:
ruby greeter_server.rb

/Users/ameynevrekar/grpc/examples/ruby/lib/helloworld_pb.rb:6:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `build' for an instance of Google::Protobuf::DescriptorPool (NoMethodError)

Google::Protobuf::DescriptorPool.generated_pool.build do
                                               ^^^^^^
    from <internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.3.0/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:127:in `require'
    from <internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.3.0/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:127:in `require'
    from /Users/ameynevrekar/grpc/examples/ruby/lib/helloworld_services_pb.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.3.0/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:127:in `require'
    from <internal:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.3.0/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:127:in `require'
    from greeter_server.rb:26:in `<main>'

I installed the desired the grpc gems as per the quick start guide

gem install grpc
gem install grpc-tools

I cloned the repository from the quick start guide
# Clone the repository to get the example code:
$ git clone -b v1.64.0 --depth 1 --shallow-submodules https://github.com/grpc/grpc
# Navigate to the "hello, world" Ruby example:
$ cd grpc/examples/ruby

I was expecting the server to run on running the command ruby greeter_server.rb


https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

updated the question with error message.

I had the same issue, downgrading to 1.64.3 resolved it for me. Looks like you've got 1.65.2 installed

The grpc ruby gem lists as a dependency google-protobuf >= 3.25, < 5.0 (see: https://rubygems.org/gems/grpc/versions/1.66.0?locale=en) but v3.25.4 was the last version of google-protobuf that seems to support the build method (see: https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/v3.25.4/ruby/lib/google/protobuf/descriptor_dsl.rb#L458-L462)
If you pin your version of google-protobuf to 3.25.4 it should work, but in general I think Google's out of the box generated lib ruby files are currently wrong (see my below comment on how to regenerate these though to support the latest google-protobuf version).

You can also update their example code if you still want to use google-protobuf > 3.25.
To do so, make sure you are in the ruby example directory (e.g. https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/examples/ruby, or the examples/ruby folder), and then run grpc_tools_ruby_protoc --ruby_out=lib --grpc_out=lib --proto_path=../protos helloworld.proto.
This , if successful, will regenerate the files in examples/ruby/lib, and now running ruby greeter_server.rb should work.
